# Want to remove Id field from Trello API Response

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-sheets, trello

Here is Twilio API Call I am using.

My Request:
https://api.trello.com/1/boards/boardID/cards/cardId?fields=name&key=MYKEY&token=MYTOKEN

My Response:
{"**id**":"570666201ffd1e340fb2e7f8","**name**":"query: show the creator of a card","**checkItemStates**":[]}

What I want:
I need to remove **Id** coming from response. And just want name ad checkedItemStates field.

Expected Response:
{"name":"query: show the creator of a card","checkItemStates":[]}

Is this possible?

**Update:**
I am importing response coming from API call to GoogleSpread sheet with provided Google Script available here. https://medium.com/@paulgambill/how-to-import-json-data-into-google-spreadsheets-in-less-than-5-minutes-a3fede1a014a#.q6wzya2yf

I am adding this equation to google spreadsheet cell

=ImportJSON("TRELLO API CALL - mentioned above ", "", "noInherit, noTruncate")

I am not using any kind of language as JSON response is directly going to google script.

Comment: "Is this possible?" ... yes of course it is, you're writing the code, right?

An example of the code, and a tag on what language we are talking about, would be helpful. 

Also "coming to response" makes no sense, I assume you mean coming *from* the response.

Comment: No, I am just using this Trello Rest api URL to import data as JSON in Google SpreadSheet. Not using any kind of code. 

Here is article explaining importing of Json data to spreadsheet.
https://medium.com/@paulgambill/how-to-import-json-data-into-google-spreadsheets-in-less-than-5-minutes-a3fede1a014a

Regarding response yes, you're assuming right. Please pardon my english.

Comment: None of that was mentioned in your question.  You should probably add as much information as possible, and exactly what steps you are taking, so that you can get a good answer.  You should include other tags in addition.

Comment: @Patrick: My apology for not adding. Just added right now.

Comment: Are you using the  ImportJSON.gs from that link?  Have you modified it?  That's the code part that we'll need to see in order to give an answer.

Comment: @Patrick: No, what I am expecting from trello response is, omit the id coming from response. This has nothing to do with the spreadsheet as it will parse whatever JSON is coming.

Comment: Are there any parameters from trello api by which I can omit Id coming from response?

Comment: No.  Are you using [ImportJSON](http://blog.fastfedora.com/projects/import-json) to do this?  Do you know how to code Google Apps Script?  You will need to do this on your side, you can not alter the items returned from the API call.

Comment: Ok. yes, I am using ImportJSON. Yes, I know. I tried but, no luck. I thought there might be some parameter, to remove. Could you please help me on Google script side?

Comment: "I am not using any kind of language" .. this is actually untrue, you are using a Google Apps script, so the language you are using is basically JavaScript.  It's not magic that is happening, it's running JSON through code via the script you are using.  See my answer below for a modified / simplified version.

Comment: twillio?? please edit your q

Comment: No, its for Trello.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this instead ... but you may need to modify this a bit to fit your needs.

```
function ImportJSON() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var url = "https://api.trello.com/1/boards/boardID/cards/cardId?fields=name&key=MYKEY&token=MYTOKEN";

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url); // Get the raw JSON

  var dataSet = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); // Parse it

  var rows = new Array();

  for (i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
    var data = dataSet[i];
    rows.push([data.name,data.email]); // your actual JSON entities here ... do not include "id"
  }

  dataRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, rows.length, 3); // 3 being the total number of entities

  dataRange.setValues(rows);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will do further changes now.

Comment: @user2617153 Let me know if you run into any problems, or accept my answer if it's helped you along.